# Synchronization of different flows in mule

Tags: mule

I have 2 flows, A.flow and B.flow, eventually both flows execute the same java class.

A & B read from a separate Queue.

I want to synchronize the flows so that if both flows get input simultaneously then one flow at a time process and after it finishes, the other flow will start processing.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: When you say "the flows process same java class" do you mean that the message payload of the message contains the same java object (class instance) or that it uses the same java object instance as a processor in the flow ? Perhaps you could clarify your question with some example flow XML.

Answer (score 2):

Use a pooled component and configure it to use one thread at a time:

```
<flow name="A">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint...>
    ...
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="process"/>
    ...
</flow>

<flow name="B">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint...>
    ...
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="process"/>
    ...
</flow>

<flow name="process">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="process"/>
    <pooled-component class="org.my.PrototypeObject">
        <pooling-profile exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_WAIT" initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ALL" maxActive="1" maxIdle="1" maxWait="1000" /> </pooled-component>
    </pooled-component>
</flow>
```

Source: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+Java+Components#ConfiguringJavaComponents-ConfiguringaPooledJavaComponent

Comment: This component would have to be in a third flow (not sub-flow) referenced by flows A and B, right?